# Remove namespace with xmltodict in Python

Tags: python, xml

[xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) converts XML to a Python dictionary.  It supports namespaces.  I can follow the example on the homepage and successfully remove a namespace.  However, I cannot remove the namespace from my XML and cannot identify why?  Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<status xmlns:mystatus="http://localhost/mystatus">
<section1
    mystatus:field1="data1"
    mystatus:field2="data2" />
<section2
    mystatus:lineA="outputA"
    mystatus:lineB="outputB" />
</status>
```

And using:

```
xmltodict.parse(xml,process_namespaces=True,namespaces={'http://localhost/mystatus':None})
```

I get:

```
OrderedDict([(u'status', OrderedDict([(u'section1', OrderedDict([(u'@http://localhost/mystatus:field1', u'data1'), (u'@http://localhost/mystatus:field2', u'data2')])), (u'section2', OrderedDict([(u'@http://localhost/mystatus:lineA', u'outputA'), (u'@http://localhost/mystatus:lineB', u'outputB')]))]))])
```

instead of:

```
OrderedDict([(u'status', OrderedDict([(u'section1', OrderedDict([(u'field1', u'data1'), (u'field2', u'data2')])), (u'section2', OrderedDict([(u'lineA', u'outputA'), (u'@lineB', u'outputB')]))]))])
```

Am I making some simple mistake, or is there something about my XML that prevents the process_namespace modification from working correctly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`xmltodict` is based on `expat`, so namespaces should applied to the class name, not attribute names:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<status xmlns:mystatus="http://localhost/mystatus">
    <mystatus:section1 field1="data1" field2="data2" />
    <mystatus:section2 lineA="outputA" lineB="outputB" />
</status>
```

When parsed with:

```
foo = xmltodict.parse(xml,
                      process_namespaces=True,
                      namespaces={'http://localhost/mystatus':None})
```

outputs:

```
OrderedDict([(u'status', OrderedDict([(u'section1', OrderedDict([(u'@field1', u'data1'), (u'@field2', u'data2')])), (u'section2', OrderedDict([(u'@lineA', u'outputA'), (u'@lineB', u'outputB')]))]))])
```

Accessing it is easy:

```
# Get attribute 'lineA' from class 'section2' from class 'status'
>>> foo.get('status').get('section2').get('@lineA')
u'outputA'
```

Attribute namespaces are only required when you have multiple attributes of the same name (e.g. multiple id's or multiple prices, etc), in which case, I couldn't get `expat` or `xmltodict` to parse it correctly. YMMV though.

Comment: I don't control the XML source, so does that mean I'm out of luck getting xmltodict to work the way I would like?  If so, can you recommend the best approach starting from the XML I show?

Comment: Sounds like it. I'm not enough of an expert on namespaces to say for sure. Ultimately, you can always extract keys with the full namespace, or write some function that removes the http://*/ prefix from the keys in the dict yourself after parsing the xmltodict tree.

Comment: Thanks.  Since my XML starts as a string, I'll just extract it from the string before parsing.  Not ideal, but now that I understand why it doesn't work, changing it via a string manipulate doesn't feel wrong.  :)