# Xml to dict how to ignore some characters when I convert my xml file to json file

Tags: python, json, xml, xmltodict

I wouldlike to remove some character when I try to convert my xml to dict :

```
data = xmltodict.parse(open('test.xml').read())

    with open('test2.json', "wt", encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
        return data
```

The problem actually i have many json file some json file like this :

```
{
        "pcrs:test A": {
            "pcrs:nature": "03", 
            "pcrs:producteur": "SIEML"
}}
```

And some json file like this(without pcrs) :

```
{
        "test B": {
            "nature": "03", 
            "producteur": "SIEML",
}}
```

How to force any file like the first example to be without `'pcrs:'` as the seconde example.

Comment: You have to check both keys when accessing the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a namespace prefix. Because you don't include sample XML, I've made up one of my own.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root_elem xmlns:pcrs="http://the/pcrs/url">
<pcrs:subelem/>
</root_elem>
```

`xmltodict` lets you manage namespaces by mapping the namespace url to a different representation. Most notably, `None` removes it completely. See [Namespace Support](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict/blob/master/README.md#namespace-support).

In your case, you can do

```
data = xmltodict.parse(open('test.xml').read(),
    process_namespaces=True,
    namespaces={"http://the/pcrs/url":None})
```

substituting the real namespace URL for `http://the/pcrs/url`.

Comment: After posting, I got to thinking that you may be dealing with namespace qualified attributes and I'm not sure if `xmltodict` handles them. This post suggests its a problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26726728/remove-namespace-with-xmltodict-in-python